# Swift/Parse - No Results Matched the Query when Updating Data

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have recently been playing around with parse,and yes, I know that it is closing soon:(. I have this error however that keeps on coming up. I am trying to update my textview.text to parse every single second. However, when the code runs a message comes up saying "no results matched the query", even though textview.text is not empty. I would really appreciate your help. Thanks.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    notes["Content"] = detailDescriptionLabel.text
    notes.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (succes, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("unable to save objects")
        }
    }
    scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.configureView()

}


func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(){
    // Scheduling timer to Call the function **Countdown** with the interval of 1 seconds
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateText"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func updateText () {

            let query = PFQuery(className: "Notes")

            query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("Content") { (notes, error) -> Void in

            notes?["Content"] = self.detailDescriptionLabel.text
            print("Updated")
            }


}
```

[Picture of error in Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJjLf.png)
[Image of Parse Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vilE2.png)

Comment: In your code you are fetching data from server, and not uploading any. Try using `somePFObject. saveInBackgroundWithBlock `  to send data to server

Comment: @ZellB. I upload information to the server in viewdidload().

Comment: But your getting no result match the query from `updateText` not from view did load

Comment: I tried adding notes.saveInBackgroundWithBlock at the bottom of "updateText", but the problem still persists.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Parse wont give "Content" to ANY of its objects as ID. Thats why no results match the query :)

Comment: @ZellB. Parse is saving objects with the ID of "Content" though. That is what makes this problem so odd, since Parse cannot retrieve theses objects and update them. I have added an image of my parse dashboard in my question to prove this. Thanks.

Comment: No the object id is not Content. Have a look at at the most left column name in dashboard. Its objectId.

Comment: @ZellB. Ohh!! I totally understand now. Thanks so much. I can believe I overlooked that. Thanks.